# Sending paramters to shell script from PHP not working?

Tags: php, shell

I am executing shell script from PHP. I am sending parameters to it from my shell_exec method in php. The script does receive the parameters and gets executed However, the if else condition will fail. I am passing R as $2 which is also getting echoed properly in the script but the if statement will simply not execute that condition and also run the else part ? When clearly in the echo i can see R being printed a s$2

When i pass the same parameters from the command line it works.

executeshellscript.php

```
<?php
/** this code handles the post ajax request**/
if(isset($_POST['getAjax'])) {

    /* you can do this below settings via your php ini also. no relation with our stuff */
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    /* setting content type as json */
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $blueid = $_POST['bluemixid'];
    $bluepwd = $_POST['bluemixpswd'];
    $env =  $_POST['env'];
    $restart =  $_POST['action'];

    $result = shell_exec('sh /var/www/shellscriptphp/webreset.sh    '.$env.'    '.$restart.'    '.$blueid.'  '.$bluepwd.'   ');
    /* making json string with the result from shell script */
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
    /* and we are done and exit */
    exit();
}

?>
```

function executeShellScript(clicked)
{

```
var blueid = $('#bluemixid').val();
var bluepwd= $('#bluemixpassword').val();
var env = $('#envoption').val();
var action = $('#actionoption').val();

//$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] is used to refer to the current page as we have the ajax target as this same page
$.post('<?PHP echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>',{"getAjax":true,"blueid":blueid,"bluepswd":bluepwd,"env":env,"action":action }, function(data) {
   // alert(data['result']);
    $("#textarea_message").val(data['result']);
    return false;
});
```

}

html

```
<tr><td>
What action you wish to perform ?
</td><td>
<select id="actionoption" >
  <option value="none">      </option>
  <option value="R" >Restart Resource Manager </option>
  <option value="O"> Restart Olympia Server </option>
  <option value="B"> Restart  Both  </option>
</select>
</td></tr>
<br>
```

webreset.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Input parameters $2 Component

echo "Input parameters: $1 $2 $3 $4"
if [ "$2" == "O" ]; then
        setRM
        restartO
        setRO
elif [ "$2" == "R" ]; then
        setrMai
        resRM
        setOperation
elif [ "$2" == "B" ]; then
        setMaintenance
        rtOlympia
        resRM
        setOperation
else
        echo "Webreset:Do nothing:Invalid option"
fi
```

OutPut:

```
Input parameters: y1 R xyz abcd
Webreset:Do nothing:Invalid option
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `elif [ $2 == "R" ];` with no double quotes around the `$2`? the same for the rest of those statements?

Comment: I tried that combination does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
elif [ "$2" == 'R' ]; then
```

See

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

For more info

`"` means expand the inside ie run the command `R`

`'` is the string